# Amazon S3 gives InvalidDigest: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, browserify

This is the solution: fix it by converting the MD5 hex to base64 instead of the string.

Example for JS (Node.js or similar, browserify, etc.

```
new Buffer(md5, 'hex').toString('base64')
```

I just spent few minutes to figure this out so I thought I could share it. :)

Comment: Your "question" is an answer, but I found it useful nevertheless :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer here! Anyways, could you please answer your own question below? I think it would be more clear when doing that :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Content-MD5` is always a base64 header.

> The base64-encoded 128-bit MD5 digest of the message (without the headers) according to RFC 1864. This header can be used as a message integrity check to verify that the data is the same data that was originally sent. Although it is optional, we recommend using the Content-MD5 mechanism as an end-to-end integrity check. For more information about REST request authentication, go to REST Authentication in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: None
>
> Constraints: None

[REST Put Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html)

Comment: Yeah but the point was that you have to convert the hex notation of your MD5 hash to base64 :)

Comment: You are right @user3376954, i thought you were asking a question here :-)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question when implementing blob upload to AWS S3 from the browser. While the chosen answer helped me understand that the `Content-MD5` needs to be a base64 string, I didn't realize that the library I used - [`md5`](https://yarnpkg.com/package/md5) was not producing MD5 in the base64 format.

I scratched my head to understand why the MD5 was invalid because it was the same value as the Etag shown on the Amazon S3 console when I manually upload it there and it turns out the ETag was also not base64.

Then I tried another library called `js-md5` that has an explicit `base64` function to produce MD5 in the base64 format and it went through.

So if you are doing the same thing from Javascript, using the `js-md5` library will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for code examples or alternatives, here are three different solutions using built-in and external libs.

NodeJS built-in:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const hash = crypto.createHash("md5").update(content).digest("base64");
```

Using [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) lib:

```js
const md5 = require("md5");
const hash = Buffer.from(md5(content), "hex").toString("base64");
```

or

```js
const md5 = require("md5");
const md5Bytes = md5(content, {
  encoding: "binary",
  asBytes: true,
});
const hash = Buffer.from(md5Bytes).toString("base64");
```

> The `content` variable may be a `string` or a `typed array` (e.g.: `Buffer`, `Uint8Array`, `Int32Array`...).